# Regex for number between 0 to 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

It should not allow leading zeroes, like `099`. Allowed values should be like these: `35`, `99`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `100`.

This is What I tried:

```
$('#createCoupon_discountAmount').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d\d?|100)\Z/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : its not working .. it accepts leading zero.

Comment: ^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$
this would be a valid regex for your problem. just specify what you would like to allow for the first number.

Comment: Just a note that regex is not really the most suitable tool for this task.

Comment: for percentage a text box should allow only digit from 0 to 100. maxLength is 3.

Answer (score 3):

The regex that I would use for this is the following, but I'm not sure if it an optimal one:

`^([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|100)$`

We create three groups and we always match from the beginning of the string to the end. The first group we capture is `[0-9]`to get the first 10 numbers (0-9). The second group we capture those numbers twice, to get all numbers from 10 -> 99. And finally we just match 100 as well.

Answer (score 3):

This version is shorter and possibly more efficient `/^([1-9]?\d|100)$/`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove leading zeros, try removing them from the beginning position using `^0+` i.e. match string starting with one or more zeros.

```
$(this).val().replace(/^0+/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the value by 1 and it will give you a perfect number